# haskell wikibook monadplus potential error

Tags: haskell

Was reading monadplus chapter of haskell wiki book: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/MonadPlus

```
digit :: Int -> String -> Maybe Int
digit i s | i > 9 || i < 0 = Nothing
          | otherwise      = do
  let (c:_) = s
  if [c] == show i then Just i else Nothing
```

"The do-block assures that any failed pattern match will result in returning Nothing."

However, when I tried `digit 1 ""`, it produces irrefutable runtime error, instead of "Nothing".

I can get around it using `(c:_) <- return s`. It would be great if someone more experienced in haskell could confirm/clarify on this.

Comment: I think that is just a bad example of parsers and of MonadPlus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in wikibooks does not account for the case when the input string is empty. When the line `let (c:_) = s` is executed and `s` is empty, it will cause a failure in the pattern matching and an exception will be thrown. Your suggestion `(c:_) <- return s` is actually quite similar to the one used, except for one difference; when the pattern matching in a monadic bind (i.e. `<-`) fails, then the `fail` method of the monad will be called. Now, in the `Maybe` monad, `fail` is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-665) to always return `Nothing`,so it will cause the whole `do` block to return `Nothing`. One thing I don't like about using your suggestion is that I personally don't consider using `fail` to be the most elegant solution and I would prefer to use a `case` expression in the case:

```
digit :: Int -> String -> Maybe Int
digit i s | i > 9 || i < 0 = Nothing
          | otherwise      =
    case s of
        c:_ | [c] == show i -> Just i
        _ -> Nothing
```

In fact, as you can see, we don't need to use a `do` block at all.

Finally, here's a more compact version of the above code:

```
digit :: Int -> String -> Maybe Int
digit i s | 0 <= i, i <= 9, c:_ <- s, [c] == show i = Just i
          | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. IOW, the claim in the wikibook, "The do-block assures that any failed pattern match will result in returning Nothing." is incorrect, right?

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Yes, you could say that